# How to relocate our source code from Vista running VisualSVN Server to Windows 7 running VisualSVN Server?

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn-server

[i meant to ask this question on StackOverflow...]

I have been using VisualSVN Server without any problem on Vista.

When it is time to change everything to Windows 7, I wonder what's the best way to do that?

Is it best to "check in" all the code from all machines onto the Vista, and do an SVN Update for one machine, and then reinstall VisualSVN on Windows 7 and create another project.  Is that the best way?

Has anybody run VisualSVN Server (as well as TortoiseSVN) on Windows 7 machine and found that it is stable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a good practice try not to run your source control on the same machine you are working on since if your PC goes down well you are going to loose everything (Use unfuddle or beanstalk , both are free). Now back to the question. I have VisualSVN running fine in Win7 as well as tortoise , to do the migration all you would need to do is make sure all your code is committed then re install in Win7 and either restore or overwrite your repo directories from VisualSVN and your projects will be back in source control , A point to note is that if your IP or machine name change you might need to do a relocate command on your working directory.

Comment: I agree about not running SVN on the same machine that you're doing development on. You loose the drive you loose everything including your source control. You might look into running a free Linux server with SVN installed on it, just so you have some speration of development from your code repository.

Comment: yes i actually sync to two other machines too.  would be good if a friend can sync to it in his house, so the data is double safe. or i can regularly FTP to my website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works with VisualSvn Server, but you want to make sure the repository uuid is the same on both repositories. You can then either do a [load/dump cycle](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnadmin) or use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync) to move the repository from one box to another.
Also take a look at [this chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) in the svnbook